# Rails : fetch first img tag from article

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, parsing

I have a website that manage article. I'd like to get the first image of these articles and display them somewhere else. Articles are stored inside a database with html code.
What are the best options for me? I already saw that I needed to parse html and that a gem called nokogiri can help me, but I have no idea what to do. I'm using rails 5.1.4 and ruby 2.4.2

Comment: You found the way, Read more about how to use nokogiri here. https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri

Comment: Post your tried code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri) to fetch the src attribute from html string. If you have `@article` as html string, Just try

```
 nokogiri_html_string = Nokogiri::HTML( @article )
 image_tag = nokogiri_html_string.css('img').first
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I'll try in a minute ! What nokogiri_html_string('img').first return if there is no img tag. Also, is it possible to only get src attribute ? Thanks

Comment: If there is no `img`, it will return an empty array. You can get the `src` attribute with `nokogiri_html_string.css('img').first['src']`